# Can we use open cart theme on clerkskart

Tags: opencart

i have a site created in open cart but now we want to convert it into clerkskart with same theme called superstar so i am curious that if we can install the same theme on the clerkskart also.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being that ClerksCart is a fork of OC, and the template system looks the same, you should be fine with only a few minor tweaks here and there.